# Revert back Push which is not merged yet

Tags: git, gitignore, git-revert

I'm working on Git-hub tool, there mistaken I push some file with local branch code which I don't want to merge in master branch. How to revert back "Push file" back to local system Or if there way to remove not require files from Github itself.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may forcibly override a branch on a remote git server, including github:

```
git push -f <server> <good_state>:<target_branch>
```

Use with care.

Perhaps more comprehensive explanations are required.

Suppose you have a repo on github. In the local clone of the repo there're commits:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

in a branch `<Branch>` (it could be `master`, or whatever), where `E` commit is "bad" (wrong, contain some erroneous or sensitive data etc). You have already pushed this branch to `github` and even created a pull request in some "parent" project.

First of all, remove the pull request, to prevent accidental merge of the E commit.

Then, drop `E` from your published commits on github:

```
 git push -f github <D>:<Branch>
```

Now on github the `<Branch>` ends with `<D>` commit as if there wasn't `<E>` at all. Now you can fix `<E>` locally, by issuing `git commit --amend`, or simply drop it with `git reset --hard <D>`. Whenever you're ready, you may push the new commits again and repeat PR.

Comment: you mean change something and create new Pull Request and delete  existing one ?

Comment: If you have already created a pull request for the bad commit, then yes, probably you should delete it. You may also remove bad commits in your personal clone of a repository on github by issuing the forementioned command.

Comment: But then what about my changes that has in open un-merged branch.

Comment: Edit them locally (use `git commit --amend`, `git reset` etc), make sure that they're correct before pushing and then push the proper versions to github.

Comment: There is bit confusion I guess. First I just wanted to remove file from Github Server Repo not from local. So if I follow you, then first I should delete open branch but but then what about changes which were part of that open branch. How I would be able to get those changes back in my local repo as modified file. #Anysuggestion here.

Comment: If you run `git push -f github <D>:<Branch>` where `<D>` is a good commit, prior to commit(s) containing a bad file, then your goal will be achieved. Bad commits remain in your local repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108879/discussion-between-shubh-and-user3159253).